# Regarding picking three elements from source list and adding to target list in first element itself

Tags: java, collections

I an interview , question was asked let say there is an array list named A of 4 elements having values 67,34,56,78 so create another array list named B  which consist of 2 elements  develop a program in such a way so that first three elements of previous arraylist A should be get inserted to array list B as shown below..

```
Arraylist A  ---> 67,34,56,78 (having size of 4)
Arraylist B   ----> 67,34,56(shoud be stored in very first element of array list itself) and 56 in next element (so total size is of arraylist B is 2)
```

and interviwer also added that as this time it was told that arraylist A will having 4 elements initially at  the starting but make another program which will be of general type means it will never be told how many elements are there in the list initially , but you have to make another list always and always pick the first three elements from the sourcelist and put in another list inside first element itself and the remaining one element of the source list as next element in the second list.

Please advise how to achieve this and how to pick the pair of 3 elements and adding it to target list.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have noo idea as i was confused which algorithm to be used for this

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes in the simplest way .. you may make it more efficient:

```
    final List<String> first = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("67");
            add("34");
            add("56");
            add("78");
        }
    };

    final List<Object> second = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // add first 3 elements to the second
    final List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        temp.add(first.get(i));
    }

    second.add(temp);
    second.add(first.get(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be Simpler

```
public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = Lists.newArrayList(67, 34, 56, 78);
        ArrayList<Integer> b = Lists.newArrayList();
        b.addAll(a.subList(0, 3));
        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

Giving

```
[67, 34, 56]
```